# Insert into select SQL with windowsForm

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to insert some data in `Table1` in my database selecting it from another `Table2` but the `Table1` has another attribute for username (*ComputerName*).

What I have tried:

```SQL
INSERT INTO [AffecAnalytique].[dbo].[C9_V] ([C9], [V], [OID], [USERMODIF]) 
SELECT [C9], [V], [OID] FROM [AffecAnalytique].[dbo].[C9_V] 
WHERE [OID] = 'CEC4F038E3954AC79DBF7EC38B02171F' ,   'AHE'
```

Comment: The code you posted does not look like valid SQL. Also the snippet does not conain any username or ComputerName columns. Could you also add the T-SQL or SQL-Server tag if this is a sql-server related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this :

```
INSERT INTO [AffecAnalytique].[dbo].[C9_V] ([C9], [V], [OID], [USERMODIF]) 
SELECT [C9], [V], [OID], 'AHE' FROM [AffecAnalytique].[dbo].[C9_V] 
WHERE [OID] = 'CEC4F038E3954AC79DBF7EC38B02171F'
```